# Can a value set in .htaccess be read in virtualhost config?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can I set a value in an htaccess file and use that value inside VirtualHost?

.htaccess:

```
SetEnv FOO bar
```

VirtualHost:

```
#...
RewriteCond %{ENV:FOO} ^bar$
# ... something
```

I assume this at least is impossible but is there any way to pass a value from .htaccess to virtualhost config? It does not necessarily need to be an environment variable to RewriteCond if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible.  VirtualHost configs are read when the apache service starts, while .htaccess files are read on demand.